# Selenium Java Webdriver, NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"btn_content"}

Tags: java, eclipse, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have been following the 2 tutorial sites below:

- https://www.guru99.com/installing-selenium-webdriver.html
- http://www.softwaretestingstudio.com/click-button-selenium-webdriver-java/

I am trying to automate a login page, but always get stuck at the “Next” button to get to the next page.

I am using:

- **Chrome browser version 61.0.3163.100**
- **Eclipse Java Oxygen**
- **JDK 9**
- **Selenium Java Client Driver 3.6.0**

Below is a snippet of the HTML for the “Next” button.

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn btn--block btn--raised primary" white--text="" style="position: relative;">
<div class="btn__content">Next</div>
</button>
```

```
package newpackage;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class T2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\struong\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    String baseUrl = "https://vertical.vappcenter.com/login";
    driver.get(baseUrl);

    // Get the WebElement corresponding to the Email Address(TextField)     
    WebElement Email = driver.findElement(By.id("email"));                                          
    // Type in an email address
    Email.sendKeys("struong@vertical.com");                                         
    // Find the Next button and click it        
    WebElement bNext = driver.findElement(By.className("btn_content"));
    // Using click method to click Next     
    bNext.click();  

    }
}
```

I get error:

> _Starting ChromeDriver 2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a) on port 5146
>   Only local connections are allowed.
>   Oct 26, 2017 3:47:13 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
>   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"btn_content"}
>     (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.62)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
>   For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
>   Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:26.402Z'
>   System info: host: 'STRUONG-DT', ip: '172.18.11.10', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '9'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=XP, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.32.498550 (9dec58e66c31bcc53a9ce3c7226f0c1c5810906a), userDataDir=C:\Users\struong\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir7400_24258}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, unhandledPromptBehavior=, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=62.0.3202.62, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
>   Session ID: eb9bec8a6c5768eb31c3168d80b3831d
>   *** Element info: {Using=class name, value=btn_content}
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:82)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:356)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByClassName(RemoteWebDriver.java:442)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByClassName.findElement(By.java:391)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:348)
>       at newpackage.T2.main(T2.java:26)_

Answer (score 0):

As error suggest, selenium is not able to find element. You can find element using text displayed as:

```
By.XPath("//button[.= 'Next']")
```